# Symfony2 background Process running after script ends?

Tags: php, symfony, background-process

Symfomaniacs!

Let's say I have this code in my controller:

```
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) 
        {
            $command = 'php ' . $kernel->getRootDir() . '/console Educa:ExecuteJob ' 
                                         . $i . ' --env=' . $kernel->getEnvironment();
            $logger->addInfo("Executing command: ".$command);
            $process = new Process($command);
            $process->disableOutput();
            $process->start();
        }
        //sleep(5);
        return $this->render(...);
```

and the ExecuteJob takes about 5 seconds to execute. Inside the console command, I have a logger->addInfo() at both the beginning and end script.

If I uncomment the ***sleep(5)*** line they both print. If I don't, only the initial line prints in the log, which must mean that **when the controller scripts end, it stops all processes**, am I wrong?

Is there any way to workaround this? I'm open to change the design, I just want to execute background stuff without having to wait to render the page (*is not even relevant* for that page)

PS: I'm looking for a way to run background tasks that **plays nice** with Symfony2, not *weird php hacks* or *cron jobs*. I know about those. I also don't want to setup a *MQ queue*. It's kind of overkill for what I'm trying.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation the perfect solution would be to use the [kernel.terminate Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-terminate-event), it's triggered after the response is streamed to the client so you can do some heavy operations there.

Comment: I was just answering myself saying that I've read that one, but I'm not sure if this is good practice or just a messy source of potential pain that I will regret forever.

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz It depends on what you want to do. If it's a little operation kernel.terminate is perfectly fine. If you want to do really heavy operations that need multiple minutes to process think about Crons and that stuff.

Comment: So let's assume it is lightweight. How do I atach it to a controller? I mean, in the example here [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) you can see it attachs it to every kernel.exception event. I don't want that. I want this code to just execute when the "Invitations Controller" terminates (ideally, when one of his methods). Is there a way to be more specific like that?

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz You can have some kind of message/event pool which you can process on kernel.terminate and put messages to the pool when you need to run your late processing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSJobQueueBundle but you will need to setup cron too

Comment: Nope. Thanks, but, as I said, no cron. TRelying in a cron is not cross-platform, for starters; you may have no control over the server to setup a cron and... a third reason. So no cron.

Answer (score -1):

Use `&` in command to send it to the background, like this

```
$command = 'php ' . $kernel->getRootDir() . '/console Educa:ExecuteJob &'
```

Comment: Could someone explain what's wrong with this approach?